Did Paul Know the High Priest Ananias well enough to Recognize Him? (Acts 22-23)
Acts 22

4 I persecuted the followers of this Way to their death, arresting
both men and women and throwing them into prison, 5 as the high priest
and all the Council can themselves testify. I even obtained letters
from them to their associates in Damascus, and went there to bring
these people as prisoners to Jerusalem to be punished.

Acts 23

The high priest Ananias ordered those standing near Paul to strike him
on the mouth. 3 Then Paul said to him, “God will strike you, you
whitewashed wall! You sit there to judge me according to the law, yet
you yourself violate the law by commanding that I be struck!” 4 Those
who were standing near Paul said, “How dare you insult God’s high
priest!” 5 Paul replied, “Brothers, I did not realize that he was the
high priest...

I have usually pictured Paul as having a working relationship with the high priest (Annas/Ananias), acting as his agent to persecute Christians. However, Acts 23 describes Paul as not being able to recognize Ananias. Some say Paul was sarcastic when he said so, others that he truly did not know the high priest on sight. Should we conclude that when Paul acted on the high priest's authority in Acts 22 - that he did not, in fact have a close working relationship with the high priest, but obtained letters from him indirectly? Was the high priest that Paul worked for a different person than Ananias, or what?

Addendum: Here is a list from the Jewish Encyclopedia giving the names of the high priests during this period. Some of the later high priests appear to be identified elsewhere by their surnames. Since Annas, Ananus and Ananias are very similar names, it is not immediately clear which of these high priests is referred to in Acts 23.


Who was Ananias of Act 23?
Paul was a Pharisee: the scriptures are full of this fact. Phil.3:5
Paul learnt under a well-known Rabbi who was also a respected Pharisee:

“I am verily a man which am a Jew, born in Tarsus, a city in Cilicia, yet brought up in this city at the feet of Gamaliel, and taught according to the perfect manner of the law of the fathers, and was zealous toward God, as ye all are this day.” (Act 22:3, KJV)

Paul's father was a pharisee!

“But when Paul perceived that the one part were Sadducees, and the other Pharisees, he cried out in the council, Men and brethren, I am a Pharisee, the son of a Pharisee: of the hope and resurrection of the dead I am called in question.” (Act 23:6, KJV)

It seems that Paul was not unknown up to the highest level of the Sanhedrin. Hence, Paul has no hiding place going by pieces of evidences of Paul before us.
Let's look at Act.23:5 again.

“And I persecuted this way unto the death, binding and delivering into prisons both men and women. As also the high priest doth bear me witness, and all the estate of the elders: from whom also I received letters unto the brethren, and went to Damascus, to bring them which were there bound unto Jerusalem, for to be punished.” (Act 22:4-5, KJV)

Paul in the above scripture, is obviously referring to his life before salvation. He described events leading to Chapter 9 when he had the divine encounter on the road to Damascus.

“And Saul, yet breathing out threatenings and slaughter against the disciples of the Lord, went unto the high priest, And desired of him letters to Damascus to the synagogues, that if he found any of this way, whether they were men or women, he might bring them bound unto Jerusalem.” (Act 9:1-2, KJV)

Paul went to "..the high priest...and desired of him letters..."
It is not clear whether he met the High Priest of the time in person or not. Whatever the case, being a pharisee of high standing, he would have seen and recognised the High Priest up to the period leading to his conversion. Besides, High priest can be recognised based on their attire even amongst the Sanhedrin.
Who was this High Priest in Act 9:1?
John Gill's Commentary says that this High priest was ... "Annas or Caiaphas, who, notwithstanding the Jews were under the Roman government, had great authority to punish persons with stripes and death itself, who acted contrary to their law." John Gill

“And the high priest Ananias commanded them that stood by him to smite him on the mouth.” (Act 23:2, KJV)

The High Priest of chapter 23 was referred to as Ananias.
According to Albert Barnes, "This Ananias was doubtless the son of Nebedinus (Josephus, Antiq., book 20, chapter 5, section 3), who was high priest when Quadratus, who preceded Felix, was president of Syria. He was sent bound to Rome by Quadratus, at the same time with Ananias, the prefect of the temple, that they might give an account of their conduct to Claudius Caesar (Josephus, Antiq., book 20, chapter 6, section 2). But in consequence of the intercession of Agrippa the younger, they were dismissed and returned to Jerusalem. Ananias, however, was not restored to the office of high priest." Albert Barnes
I reckon there was a sufficient time gap between chapters 9 and 23 so that they are not the same high priests. This time gap is difficult to determine. How was it that the council could not recognise Paul of Chapter 9? It seems this was a council different from what he knew in Chapter 9. No one in the council meeting referred to his past as Saul of Tarsus. Since, Paul's conversion, he abandoned living like a Pharisee in his personal life. Phil.3:7-8. Paul had withdrawn from active participation in pharisaical life since his conversion. There was a time he was away for three years in Arabia.
Why didn't Paul recognise the High Priest Ananias in Chapter 23?
Paul knew he was before the council/Sanhedrin. Act 23:1. He would have expected the High Priest to be dressed in his office robe (not Hight Priest attire for temple worship) since it was a formal gathering of the council. Paul's opening plea showed he knew that he was before the Sanhedrin. Act.23:1.
Why didn't he see the High Priest? The most probable reason must be that Paul had a problem with his sight at this time. His vision must be so blurry that he could not tell who was who. All he could depend on was his perception. Act.23:6.

+1, but a comment regarding the last section. Both Annas and Caiaphas, IIRC, are called the "high priest" in the Gospels. High priest at some point became a political position and could be (and was) changed at will by the ruler. So apparently we have a situation where Caiaphas is the "official" high priest, but Annas is respected as a previous high priest and father of multiple others. That being so, it's possible this is the same Ananias in Acts 23 and he isn't wearing robes, since he isn't officially the high priest, yet they'd expect him to be shown the same respect.

In that case, in Acts 22:4-5 he's referring not to Ananias, but to Caiaphas or whoever was high priest at the time. Having said that, it still seems improbable that he never saw Ananias, so quite likely poor eyesight was also a factor.

@user111403 Thank you for the comment and observation. I did consider your point as well, but what beats me was that no one in the Sanhedrin of Act 23:1 recognised Paul! That's a big issue for me, even if Paul never met any of the High Priests in Person in Act 9:1. How can no one recognise Saul the Church destroyer? Not a single pharisee or sadducce could recognise him. Your point is also a possibility. Thank you

I don't really see in the text confirmation that no one recognized Paul. Some may well have known that Paul and Saul are the same person and would expect to recognize him. For the rest, while Saul seems to have been fairly well-known, it's not clear if he ever appeared before the Sanhedrin, so some might have known of him but not known him by sight. And several years have passed, Paul probably looks quite a bit older after all he went through on his journeys. Would you recognize someone you met just a couple times ten years ago?

Good info but... Is there evidence that the high priest wore his vestments outside of the Temple? This site says it was forbidden to do so.

@Dan Fefferman. Thank you for the observation. Mk.14:53-54,63 is a good example. Jesus was before a council in the PALACE of the High Priest. "...the High Priest rent his clothes ..' vs 63. I believe this is similar to what Paul faced in Act.23:1-2. The High Priest was dressed (whatever he wore) for the council meeting ready for Paul.

The High Priest rent his clothes - I don't think anyone is suggesting that the High Priest walked around naked the rest of the time. He was wearing something, so he had something to rend. If anything, the rending suggests it wasn't his Temple garments.

@user111403. I have edited the part of High Priest clothes in the main response. I agree that he was not putting on Temple garments as I have done more research on it. Thanks for the observation.

What do we know about the life of Saul/Paul?
Paul then reveals a new detail about his identity:
Ῥωμαῖον! “I am a Roman!” The tribune is filled with admiration: he himself had purchased his citizenship at great cost! Paul replies, “But I was born with this right” (Acts 22:25-28)!
The Letters confirm that Paul was born a Jew, as he was circumcised on the eighth day of his birth, was the son of Jews, belonged to the tribe of Benjamin, was an Israelite, and a speaker of Aramaic (Phil. 3:4-5; Rom. 9:3b-5, Rom. 11:1, 2 Cor. 11:22).
Claiming to be from Tarsus in antiquity was no small thing: before Paul, Strabo had stated that the citizens of this city had surpassed Athens and Alexandria in their schools and in the teaching of philosophers (Strabo 14.5.12-15); after Paul, Dio Chrysostom continued to list the reasons for the pride of the citizens of Tarsus for their city (Dio Chrys. 33.17, 33.28); even later, though considering that philosophy mattered little to them, Philostratus mentioned the luxury of these citizens (Philostr. Apoll. Tyan. 1.7), and an inscription even claimed Tarsus as “the first, the greatest, and the most beautiful metropolis” (OGIS 578.7.8).
Indeed, the Paul of Acts was not only a citizen of Tarsus but also a citizen of Rome (Acts 16:37-38, 22:25-29, 23:27, 25:10-12).
Silas/Silvanus, Paul's companion, is also considered to be a Roman citizen (Acts 16:37); in Jerusalem, there were Jews who were Roman knights (Josephus, AJ 14.228, 232, 234, 237, 240, 19.52, BJ 2.308). It is admittedly strange that Paul, if he were truly a Roman citizen, was flogged three times (2 Cor. 11:25. Cf. 2 Cor. 6:5, 11:23-24). However, there was certainly a gap between the letter of the law and its enforcement: for example, Roman citizens are known to have been crucified despite their status (Jones, 1968; Hengel, 1977).
The Roman soldier Saul/Paul in the Pauline letters explains the mission of the Christian as a preparer of this new order, expressed in the metaphor of the militia Christi, where the spiritual significance of the military lexicon is exposed: 1 Tim. 6:12; 2 Tim. 2:3; 2 Cor. 10:3-4; Eph. 6:11-17; 1 Thess. 5:8.
After providing this context, we can better understand these two texts:
2 Corinthians 5:16 says:

"So from now on, we regard no one from a worldly point of view; though we once regarded Christ in this way, we do so no longer."

Acts 26:9-10

“I too was convinced that I ought to do all that was possible to oppose the name of Jesus of Nazareth. And that is just what I did in Jerusalem. On the authority of the chief priests, I put many of the Lord’s people in prison, and when they were put to death, I cast my vote against them”

Saul used his influence as a Roman military along with some of the chief priests in Jerusalem to persecute Christians, because in his mind, since he had known Jesus while he was still alive, it was impossible for Him to have been resurrected, as Hellenistic culture thought.
Did Paul Know the High Priest Ananias well enough to Recognize Him? The answer is no. Paul only knew some of the Priests due to his influence as a Roman Jew, of Greek culture..
